# How can I scrape and record both price and date of a product with Python and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code goes like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Atomic-Habits-James-Clear-audiobook/dp/B07RFSSYBH/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=atomic+habits&qid=1685192621&s=books&sprefix=atomi%2Cstripbooks-intl-ship%2C315&sr=1-1'

HEADERS = ({'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US, en:q =0.5'
})

page = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)  
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(),"html.parser")
title = soup2.find(id = 'product Title').get_text()
price = soup2.find("span",  attrs ={"class": 'a-size-base a-color-secondary'}).text

print(title)
print(price)

price = price.strip()[1:]
title = title.strip()
    
print(price)
print(title)
 
today = datetime.date.today()
print(today)

# inserting data into excel

header = ['title', 'price', 'Date']
data = [title, price, today]

with open('AmazonWebScraper.csv', 'w', newline='',encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(data)   
    
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\AmazonWebScraper.csv')
print(df)
```

Can anybody help me fix this, I don't see any error but the code isn't being executed?
I'm trying to put it through the end as a beginner on python.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this way:

```py
import datetime
import csv
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Atomic-Habits-James-Clear-audiobook/dp/B07RFSSYBH/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=atomic+habits&qid=1685192621&s=books&sprefix=atomi%2Cstripbooks-intl-ship%2C315&sr=1-1'

headers = ({'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US, en:q =0.5' })

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
# print(soup.prettify())
title = soup.find(id='productTitle'). get_text()
price = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": 'a-size-base a-color-secondary'}).text

price = price.strip()
title = title.strip()
today = datetime.date.today()

header = ['title', 'price', 'Date']
data = [title, price, today]

with open('AmazonWebScraper.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer. writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(data)

df = pd.read_csv(r'AmazonWebScraper.csv')
print(df)
```

output: `AmazonWebScraper.csv`

```
   title                                              price   Date
0  Atomic Habits: An Easy & Proven Way to Build G...  $12.99  2023-05-30
```

Comment: I tried it now and it worked perfectly. Can u please explain to me where was my mistake, so I won't repeat it next time? And is it normal that I don't see the column of Date added to the CSV file, or should I be adding something else at the code?

Comment: I tried by adding:                                                                                                                                                                        with open ('AmazonWebScraper.csv' ,'a+', newline = '',encoding ='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv. writer(f)
    writer . write row(data)                                                                               but it didn't change anything on the csv file. What do u suggest me to do?

Comment: you should read the CSV file from the same path where you've written it, if you see in your code, the path to write and read the file is different. and the Date column is already getting written in the file along with title and price.

Comment: Yes indeed, just like u said. I fixed the path even for appending and now it's working correctly, till the end. Thank u very much, appreciate the willingness to help and the explanation also.